# android - apply button default style to linear layout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, android-styles

I want to have a button with multiple TextViews - so I figured I should have a linearlayout and put Textviews inside.

I want the linearlayout to look exactly like the button, and I can't achieve that.

**Here is how the button "Add Ride" looks like (not the blue title, the grey button):**

[image]

and the button code is like this, without any style:

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnAddRide"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
     android:text="Add Ride" />
```

**How do I make the linearlayout look like this??**

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should add to you linear layout is:

```
android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the default look of the button. So, if you want your linearlayout too have a look like this then I guess, you will have to take the color of button and have that as background of linearlayout something like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/<btn_bg_color>"
    android:orientation="vertical"
/>
```